# Barrier with an async postPhaseAction in C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, barrier

I need to use an `async` method as the `postPhaseAction` of `Barrier`, for different reasons, including the ability to cancel the method. In the following example, the `postPhaseAction` saves items in a list to a database, which can cooperate with the cancellation request.

```cs
var entities = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
var barrier = new Barrier(0, async (_) =>
{
    var context = GetDatabaseContext();
    await context.Entities.AddRangeAsync(entities, cancellationToken);
    await context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

The issue with this approach is that the `barrier` does not wait for the `postPhaseAction` to conclude, which can result in concurrently running multiple delegations of `postPhaseAction`.

Comment: Have you looked at the [`Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.AsyncBarrier`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.threading.asyncbarrier)?

Comment: Yes, I did. The root of that docs page reads, `You should use these APIs for asynchronous programming in Visual Studio.` I am not sure if it implies these APIs are for VS only.

Comment: I don't understand why you specifically need a `Barrier`. My understanding of `Barrier` is that it allows for multiple participants to move through various phases, alerting the barrier that they've concluded. That doesn't seem to be the use case here.

Comment: Do you use any other method/property of the `Barrier` class, other than the `SignalAndWait`? I am asking because you might have to resort to a custom implementation. Btw the [AsyncEx](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.AsyncEx/) library once included an [`AsyncBarrier`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/v4/Source/Nito.AsyncEx%20(NET45%2C%20Win8%2C%20WP8%2C%20WPA81)/AsyncBarrier.cs) component, but [it has been removed](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/master/doc/upgrade.md#asyncbarrier).

Comment: Original idea by Stephen Toub: [Building Async Coordination Primitives, Part 4: AsyncBarrier](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/building-async-coordination-primitives-part-4-asyncbarrier/).

Comment: I am using `Barrier` extensively; the code provided here merely servers the minimal reproducible example purposes. I am happy to add other parts if needed, though I would prefer to keep rolling my alternative of `Barrier` as the last option.

Comment: Is it an option to `Wait` synchronously the `AddRangeAsync` and `SaveChangesAsync`, instead of `await` them asynchronously?

Comment: Are you suggesting `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`? If so, I guess that is generally a frowned-upon approach.

Comment: [Blocking on async code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) is frowned upon indeed, but the disadvantages of doing so are usually exaggerated. If you know what you are doing it's OK. It's not ideal, but if the alternative is to implement an `AsyncBarrier` from scratch, the `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` is not only easier but also has a lower risk factor. Someone could question why you need to use a `Barrier` in the first place, but we assume that you know what you are doing.

Comment: The alternative for me is using `SaveChanges` which blocks as expected. But the downside to that is I cannot cancel the operation and need to wait until it finishes. In my case, that can result in ~4-5min wait time, which I am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

The Barrier class takes an Action which has a void return value and cannot be awaited.

Comment: Is there any good workaround?

Comment: Not usually recommended, but you could try putting that on another method and invoking `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` on the returning task.

Comment: True, I am hopping not to go down that road.